# How to reduce spacing between vertical sliders?

Tags: gui-construction, interface, slider

Consider the following code:

```
Row[
 Table[
  With[{i = i},
   x = ConstantArray[0.5, 3];
   Column[{i, 
     VerticalSlider[Dynamic@x[[i]], Appearance -> "Labeled", 
      ImageSize -> Small]}, Alignment -> Center]
   ],
  {i, 1, 3, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

It creates 3 vertical sliders which are widely spaced apart. How can I reduce the spacing between them?

One more thing, I wish to interchange the positions of the slider indices and their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Row[Table[With[{i = i}, x = ConstantArray[0.5, 3];
Column[{i, 
 VerticalSlider[x[[i]], Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> 30],
  "      "}, Alignment -> Center]], {i, 1, 3, 1}]]
```

you can manipulate spacing by adding spaces at "     "

---

here are slider indices and their values placed at the bottom

```
Row[Table[With[{i = i}, x = ConstantArray[0.5, 3];
Column[{VerticalSlider[Dynamic@x[[i]], Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ImageSize -> 30], "      ", i}, Alignment -> Center]], {i, 1, 3,
1}]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One observation: if you try to reduce the height, it creates a big gap between the sliders and their corresponding values.

Comment: I made one more change and it looks better. You can now separate them as much as you want

Comment: just add spaces at "    "

Comment: Or use the function [`Spacer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spacer.html)

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
Row[
  Table[With[{i = i}, x = ConstantArray[0.5, 3];
    Column[{i, 
            VerticalSlider[Dynamic@x[[i]], 
                           Appearance -> "Labeled", 
                           ImageSize -> 30]},
            Alignment -> Center]
    ],
    {i, 1, 3, 1}], 
  Spacer[10] (* Row second parameter is a separator between successive elements *)
]
```

Comment: I see that you edit my code and not OP's...

Comment: 30 is a good size. I agree.

Comment: Yes, changing "Small" to "30" was the key! Spacer wouldn't work otherwise.